# Why is the time taken by powershell code to convert a file to base64 varying from 10-50s from the day I moved from win7 to win10?

Tags: windows, powershell

Powershell Code used to convert a file into Base64 format:

```
param(
        [Parameter(Position=0,mandatory=$true)]
        [String] $FilePath,
        [Parameter(Position=1,mandatory=$true)]
        [String] $Base64OutPutFilePath
) 

$FileContent= Get-Content -Path $FilePath -Encoding Byte
$FileContentBase64= [System.convert]::ToBase64String($FileContent) 
$FileContentBase64 | Out-File $Base64OutPutFilePath
```

Comment: Is the input file the exact same in both cases? Are you still running on the same hardware? Did you replace your AV? Waaaaaay to many variables here (and way too little information for anyone to be able to guess why)

Comment: Also, `Get-Content -Encoding Byte` is traditionally slow as hell, please look into the `ReadCount` parameter

Comment: `[byte[]]$FileContent = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($FilePath)` should be a lot faster

Answer (score 0):

This should be faster:

```
param(
        [Parameter(Position=0,mandatory=$true)]
        [String] $FilePath,
        [Parameter(Position=1,mandatory=$true)]
        [String] $Base64OutPutFilePath
             ) 

    [byte[]]$FileContent = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes( $FilePath )
    $FileContentBase64 = [System.convert]::ToBase64String($FileContent) 
    [System.IO.File]::WriteAllText( $Base64OutPutFilePath, $FileContentBase64 )
```